# TeXmaker 4.4.1-1 function keys don't work after upgrading (14.10 - 15.04)

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, latex, function-keys

I was using version 4.4.1 but after upgrading from Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 the function keys didn't work anymore (e.g. F1 for Quick Build, F6 for PDFLaTeX, etc.).
I reinstalled TeXmaker via `apt-get` with no avail, but found out that when I install TeXmaker 4.4.1 from the web page for Ubuntu 15.04 they work, but I get a notification that a newer version is available shortly after.
The newest version is 4.4.1-1 and there the functions keys don't work anymore so I end up using version 4.4.1 from the web page and getting the notification every now and then.
Is this a 4.4.1-1 problem or Ubuntu 15.04 and how can I use function keys with the newest version?

Comment: can you specify which function keys you're talking about and what they're supposed to do?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. None of them work. F1 for quickbuild, F2 for LaTeX, etc.

Comment: I have the same issue on 15.10!  None of the function shortcut keys (F1 - F12) work, but clicking on the menu-item for the same functionality works.

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution: Go download and install a newer DEB package from the [Texmaker website](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#linux).**

**NOTE :** Simply trying to overwrite the package using `dpkg -i` will fail with an error. You first need to uninstall the `texmaker-data` package (which will also remove `texmaker` and a few more dependencies):

```
sudo apt-get remove texmaker-data
```

Then install the downloaded package ( this is for 15.10, 64-bit ):

```
sudo dpkg -i texmaker_ubuntu_15.10_4.5_amd64.deb
```